# Installing kali linux on lenovo yoga 2 pro

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, partitioning, lenovo-laptop

Got various problems installing Kali using UNETBOOTin. Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro bought in 2014. Just want to completely remove windows and replace entirely with kali.

1. Wireless card not found, trying to install and I can't get anywhere because of the wifi. The wifi only work on UEFI boot and nothing else. On live, i tried to `sudo rmmod ideapad-laptop` then `sudo service network-manager restart`, but that only activates bluetooth. Doesn't even show up on rfkill.

2.I deleted my windows partition, according to Gparted. But I can still access windows.

Comment: On 1: try `lsusb`, `lspci`, `sudo lshw` and see if the wireless card is appearing.  Then edit your question to tell us what it is.  Not sure, but there may be some cards that it just doesn't cooperate with.

Comment: On 2: deleting the partition just means the indication that there's another partition was removed from the MBR, but the data in the partition space was not removed. Your old windows data will persist as long as nothing overwrites it.  I suggest you boot into live and then let the installer reformat the whole disk while it installs.  If you need internet to install, you might do that with a temporary wired connection.

Comment: On 1: Maybe you could try a live Ubuntu to see if  that's able to see the wireless.  If I remember, Kali is based on ubuntu, or maybe debian.

Comment: @Diagon it runs debian i pretty sure.

Comment: And ubuntu is based on debian, so that will still be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo's BIOS design for Yoga machines precludes installing it, or any Linux install. See https://news.lenovo.com/pressroom/press-releases/lenovo-statement-on-linux-support-for-yoga/